# Почему не сохраняется файл в phpstorm?

Tags: phpstorm

Есть проект, в нем не могу сохранить отредактированный файл в phpstorm. Причем некоторые файлы после редактирования сохраняются, некоторые нет, с ошибкой:

> operation not permitted

И еще в конце имени файла появляется **jb_bak**, тоже не пойму почему. Хочу заметить, что права у файлов, которые сохраняются и нет, одинаковые.

[image]